# PluralTranslatableMarkup does not return plural value

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

The code bellow should return `plural`.

```
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\PluralTranslatableMarkup;

$trans = new PluralTranslatableMarkup(12, 'singular', 'plural');
$output = '' . $trans;
$output1 = $trans->render();
```

Both `$output` and `$output1` returns `singular`;

Any clues why? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with other numbers? What is the language set for the site?

Comment: yes, however it seems like this is core bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2660338

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known bug tracked on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2660338).

Comment: @leymannx I do agreee, but I still do not know what should I pick when flagging this question ( Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic ). I guess it is nor ok to delete the question doe? :)

Comment: There's this one flagging option where you can enter a text yourself. Regarding deleting the question altogether I'd prefer leaving it here to help others to find the issue on drupal.org more easily. :)